# Do I always have to apply a function (anonymous or otherwise) to pass JavaScript parameters for an event handler?

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I am having difficulty finding details on the completely correct syntax for passing parameters for an event in JavaScript. It appears that I ALWAYS have to create a function in order to get parameters to the function from the event handler... and it just looks odd and unnecessary. Here is example code:

```
function styleSet(id1,id2,styleType)
{
    document.getElementById(id1).style[styleType] = document.getElementById(id2).value;
}

document.getElementById("pFamilyID").onkeyup = function(){styleSet("paraID","pFamilyID","fontFamily")};
```

That event will work fine but I have created an anonymous function in order to apply the parameters. If I try to just pass the parameters like:

```
element.onkeyup = styleSet("paraID","pFamilyID","fontFamily");
```

... then it will not work. So the question is; do I always have to create that function when I am passing parameters or is there a more efficient method?

Comment: What is `onKeyUp` handler? a function that gets invoked when that even is triggered, so to override it you have to provide your own `function` and not only a statement; hence the need for that syntax

Comment: Hanky - The code is only an example to illuminate my question. pFamilyID is just a text box that I am typing a web font into and paraID is just the paragraph that is being affected by the font change. Like I said it works fine but I am just wondering why I would have to put the function inside another one to get it to operate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesnt work as you do two different things

The function working is a property **assignment**, the property (the function) gets called when the event occurs

The second is an **invocation** as you asign the result of your function to the property which gets invoked on keydown which doesnt work.

Note that most event driven functions receive the event as a first parameter (beside others, check `arguments`).

So you have to wrap it in an anonymous function or at a least provide a function which matches the signature of the invocation of the keyup event

Comment: I think I know what you mean now. I am probably looking at it the wrong way. The anonymous function is effectively just handing the event but the changes that are being applied are a different action. Makes sense.

Comment: Hey, in fact that makes tons of sense now... I can put a load of functions (similar to the styleSet function) inside of the anonymous function. The event handling function is literally just a trigger for further events to take place. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you mess up the declaration of a function with calling a function. this.onkeyup=function(params){...} is just a decaration, when you call it, use" this.onkeyup(params);".
The purpose to write function in this way is to maintain OO style. The OO style is a little different with java or c# in js.

Comment: Yes, I believe I see what you mean. I started with java and C# classes and found JavaScript a bit odd when I started using it. I am beginning to understand the OO of JavaScript now I think. Thank you.